# Calculus and polynomial analysis

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials, definite-integrals

[image]

Work till now:

So in this problem, clearly the third root is $-b/a$. Also it becomes clear after solving $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ that $b=(-d)$ and $a=(-c)$. Also from the graph of $1-|x|$ in interval $[-1,1]$, it is clear that $d>=1$ and thus $b<=-1$ and thus $f(x)>=0$ in interval $(-1,1)$. The derivative at $x=-1$ is also to be positive since $f(x)>1-|x|$ on $(-1,1)$ and thus graph only rises at $x=-1$. From that I saw that $a-b>0$. Also the third root $-b/a$ is either less than $-1$ or greater than $1$. Now i cant figure out how to proceed so as to minimise the integral asked. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You want to minimise $\frac85a^2+\frac23(2b-1)^2$ and you already have found $b\leqslant -1$.  So for the minimum $b=-1$.  Similarly, what can you say about $a$, whose best choice is clearly $a=0$ if that’s allowed?

Comment: so is evaluating the integral manually the only option to proceed ? I thought maybe some other observation can simplify the calculations so i got stuck. Thanks.

Comment: You can simplify using $1-x^2$ is a factor to express $f$ in terms of just $a, b$ before integrating, however you will need to integrate sometime.